# How to create display page depending on role?

Tags: theming, users

I have a role of **shopkeeper** who is able to update the *product info*. But I want to create a different page for specific role of user. How to do this

Answer (score 0):

Try [**Front Page**](https://www.drupal.org/project/front) Module

**Features**

> The Front Page module allows for customised home pages dependant on role. The pages can be of the following types:
>
> - **Alias (only 2.x branch)** - Allows for another Drupal path to be shown as the home page without redirecting the user.
> - **Redirect** - Allows you to redirect users to a local or remote URL.
> - **Themed** - Allows you to enter some static text that will be placed into the content area of a standard Drupal page.
> - **Full** - Allows for static content to be displayed to the screen as is. This method does not pass through Drupal's theming system.

Hope this will help you..

Answer (score 0):

[Content Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access)

> This module allows you to manage permissions for content types by role
>   and author. It allows you to specify custom view, edit and delete
>   permissions for each content type. Optionally you can enable per
>   content access settings, so you can customize the access for each
>   content node.

**OR**

Showing different content on the same page to user depending on role could be accomplished with the Panels module like so:

- Install the [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) module and its dependencies.
- Go to admin » structure » panels.
- Enable and edit the page "node_view" template.
- Click "add new variant".
- Click "continue" on each screen until there is a button with "Add
  variant."
- Click "Add variant".
- Under panel » content, click the gear in the upper left to add a
  panel of content for the logged in user to see. Save.
- Click the gear in the upper right of the new content to get a menu.
  Select visibility rules » add new rule. Select role and set it how
  you want. Save.
- If you want to show something different to anonymous users, repeat
  step 6 and 7 to add content and make it visible only to anonymous
  users.
- Don't forget to save.

it is explain by [beth](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/89003/display-different-content-on-node-pages-depending-on-user-role)